# How to type input to `mergeDeepRight`

Tags: typescript, ramda.js

I have function

```
const updateStoreMerge = (value: PartialRecursive<StoreType>): StoreType => updateStore(s => mergeDeepRight(s, value));
```

how to type it? `Value` should be just subset of `StoreType`. I want something like partial but recursively put nullability to all attributes.

```
type PropsThatAreObjects<T, K extends keyof T> = K extends keyof T ? T[K] extends object ? K : never : never;

type PartialAll<T> = {
  [K in PropsThatAreObjects<T, keyof T>]?: PartialAll<T[K]> &
  [K in keyof T except the ones in PropsThatAreObjects<T, keyof T>]?: T<K> 
};
```

I have problem writing this

```
[K in keyof T except the ones in PropsThatAreObjects<T, keyof T>]?: T<K>
```

Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to me that `PartialAll` (or `PartialRecursive`) could be simplified to this:

```js
type PartialAll<T> = T extends object ? { [K in keyof T]?: PartialAll<T[K]> } : T;
```

Comment: Wow this is so easier than mine thing! You are right, this is correct. But for whatever reason it still does not typecheck..

Comment: I'll be happy to help but I need some more information than that. Ideally an example where I can reproduce the issue.

Comment: If you want sure. This is simplified example:
```
type A = {x: number, y: { z: string}};
const state: A = {x: 123, y: {z: 'zzz'}};
const merge = (a: PartialAll<A>): A => mergeDeepRight(state, a);
```
I merge A with PartialAll<A> and want to get A back. mergeDeepRight is from Ramda. And I do deep merge, not normal merge, otherwise I could use spread..

Comment: But this is good enough
```
const updateStoreMerge = (value: PartialAll<StoreType>): StoreType => updateStore(s =>
  // @ts-ignore
  mergeDeepRight(s, value)
);
```

Comment: Instead of @ts-ignore you could at least cast the result to `StoreType`... so: `updateStore(s => mergeDeepRight(s, value) as StoreType)`

Comment: Thanks Lukas , I did it that way :)